# declaration regarding the content variable

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scala-template

I am new playwork. I have been going through the tutorials and samples provided the playframework.
I could successfully render helloworld application provided by playframework samples.
I have few doubts regarding the rendering part of main.scala.html.#

This is the default program which I got from **samples/helloworld**

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <a href="@routes.Application.index">@title</a>
        </header>

        <section>
            @content
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here when I commented out the @content under section tag , I am not able to see the the fields.
Now my question is, where is @content is mapped to the Form field?

I created another structure for my layout and added the @content to the content section. but it does not fit into that
so now my question is @content where is that defined that it is div container and has got some height and weight and all?
I could not understand. Please help me.
Pleae find my customized code below

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>


<body>

<div id="container" style="width:500px">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
HTML<br>
CSS<br>
JavaScript</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
@content</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © W3Schools.com</div>






</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

From [Template parameters](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates) in the Play Template documentation, the meaning of the first line is described. Here, we see that two parameter groups are required.

The two parameter groups are:

1. a `String` parameter containing the title
2. a `Html` parameter containing some HTML content

**Usage**

To use this template, two parameter groups have to be supplied. In the context of the helloworld application, it is called from `app/views/index.scala.html` like this:

```
@main(title = "The 'helloworld' application") {
  <h1>Configure your 'Hello world':</h1>
  ... more HTML elided
}
```

This pattern is described in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases, where HTML is injected into a template.

- `main.scala.html` contains the template (`content` contains the HTML to be injected).
- `index.scala.html` contains an example of injection into this template.

Note that calling `@main(...)` calls the template that is defined in `main.scala.html`.Similarly, calling `@my_template(...)` would call the template defined in `my_template.scala.html`.

In this case, the HTML for the form is defined inside `index.scala.html`.

**Calling the Template**

Finally, the root template is called from a controller. For the helloworld application, the template defined in `index.scala.html` is invoked by the code

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(html.index(helloForm))
}
```

This is where the form object is injected into the template.